# Java can't find constructor

Tags: java

I feel that I'm going about this code the wrong way. Essentially i am attempting to load client information from a text file. My troublesome code looks like this...

```
//load clients data from file
        file = new File(clientsOutputFile);
        sc = new Scanner(file);
        Client client;
        String givenName, familyName;
        String industry, projectName;
        // iterate for each line in venues file, one by one
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            str = sc.nextLine();
            // split line by tab
            parts = str.split("\t");
            // check if all details of client are provided
            if(parts.length == 5) {
                phone = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                givenName = parts[1];
                familyName = parts[2];
                industry = parts[3];
                projectName = parts[4];
                client = new Client(phone, givenName, familyName, industry, projectName);
                // add client to client's model
                clientMdl.addElement(client);
            }
        }
        sc.close();
```

the error that I receive upon compile is...

```
    Error: /Users/Desktop/Migration/BookingGUI.java:647: cannot find
symbol
symbol  : constructor Client(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class Client
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Client class doesn't have a constructor that matches with your parameters.

Comment: Without seeing the code for `Client`, it's hard to know how to help you. Presumably it just doesn't have that constructor... so add it, or use a constructor that *does* exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You class should have a constructor with parameter of type

class Client {

```
public Client(int phone, String givenName, String familyName,
              String industry, String projectName) {
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a constructor that has the parameters. Java will put a default but I have always found it to be unreliable.

Comment: What in the world do you mean by "unreliable"?

Comment: I guess I should rephrase it. It was beaten into my head in school to always put no arg constructors because certain classes can look for it and keep the program from throwing InstantiationException. Hope that explains it a little better!!

Comment: Not in real-world code; if a class has a hard dependency on a collaborator or configuration information, then there's no problem not using a no-arg constructor. Modern DI frameworks can handle constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `public` (or package-private if `BookingGUI` is in the same package) constructor in the `Client` class that accepts all the arguments you are trying to pass.

For example:

```
class Client {
    // declare instance variables

    public Client(String phone, String givenName, String familyName,
                  String industry, String projectName) {
        // set instance variables
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you lookup if `Client` class really has a constructor wich has four parameters?? This must have a constructor like this:

```
public class Client {
         ///fields
    public Client(String a, String b, String c, String d){
         //class initiation
    }
}
```

Another cause of this problem can be that `Client` class have this constructor with `private` modifier, so, you can't instantiate it.